# LyX + SyncTeX + Document Viewer Evince

Tags: lyx, viewers, evince

I am running LyX 2.0.2 in Ubuntu 12.04 and using the default PDF viewer Evince.

I want to setup SyncTeX to go back and forth between the document and the source, at the right position in the text.

I found this in the LyX website, but it doesn't give the Evince viewer.
http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX

Does anybody know how to set it up?

Comment: You might want to try using a newer version of LyX by using the [PPA](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3)

Comment: I tried the instructions on the PPA, but with no success on getting the newer version.  Would you say upgrading through the Synaptic Manager could be useful instead?

Comment: sorry the instructions didn't work for you. I've not heard that before. If you want to say exactly which steps you did and where it went wrong, I might have some ideas. Well, I don't think there are any updates in Synaptic Manager. Unless you added the PPA in which case you can update through Synaptic Manager. Finally, if you don't get an answer here, consider emailing lyx-users (linking to this thread) with your question.

Comment: The update did work with Synaptic.  This is what I did.
I followed instructions in the link for the PPA above, I wrote "/release" for the stable release instead of "/daily".  Then I opened Synaptic Manager and updated it from there.

Comment: Ah, so when you wrote "with no success" what do you mean? Or it is resolved now?

Comment: Thanks the upgrading is resolved. But I'm waiting for lyx-users to respond about SyncTeX.  I wrote with no success because I didn't know to use Synapctic with PPA.

Comment: Hopefully you find out. If not, you can always install Okular with `sudo apt-get install okular` but it will probably be a large install for you because of the KDE library dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's no easy way to do this, yet.

### Modifying Scripts

- [Download files](http://dud.inf.tu-dresden.de/~ben/evince_synctex.tar.gz). (They are from **Benjamin Kellermann**, originally [posted to Ubuntuusers](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/evince-synctex-vim-emacs-scite-lyx-kile-editor/#post-2818861) on March 2011, based on an older version of the [Gedit Synctex Plugin](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit-plugins/tree/plugins/synctex/synctex) by **Jose Aliste**.)
- Extract them, e.g. to your desktop.
- Rename the file `evince` to `evince-synctex`. (To be sure that this file will be started because `/usr/bin/evince` will be found first in `PATH`.)
- Open this file (`evince-synctex`) and replace the second line (starting with `EDITORCMD`) to

  ```
  EDITORCMD="lyxclient -g %f %l"
  ```
- In file `evince_backward_search`, replace the line

  `cmd = re.sub("%f",input_file,self.editor)`
  with

  ```
  cmd = re.sub("%f",input_file.split("file://")[1],self.editor)
  ```

  Be sure that this text aligns with the text of the lines afterwards. (That change is needed because it seems that LyX can't handle filenames starting with "file://".)
- Move all three files (`evince-synctex`, `evince_backward_search`, `evince_forward_search`) to `/usr/local/bin` (needs root rights). (That's the place where user scripts should be stored.)

### Extra for Evince 3.4.0 (= Ubuntu 12.04)

In file `evince_forward_search`, replace the last line (starting with `window.SyncView(`) with

```
window.SyncView(tex_file, (line_number,1), int (time.time ()), dbus_interface="org.gnome.evince.Window")
```

### Setting up LyX

- In *Document > Settings > Output*, check *Synchronize with output*
- In *Tools > Preferences > Output > General > PDF command*, write `evince_forward_search $$o $$n $$t`
- Change PDF Viewer (*Tools > Preferences > File Handling > File Formats > PDF (pdflatex)*) to `evince-synctex`.

### Backward Search (Evince -> LyX)

- Open file in LyX, view "PDF (pdflatex)".
- Hold Ctrl key and (left-)click on the line you want to edit. It should be shown in LyX now.

### Forward Search (LyX -> Evince)

- Open file in LyX, view "PDF (pdflatex)".
- Right-click on one line (in LyX), choose "forward search".

Comment: In a modern Linux environment (I'm using Arch Linux), you'll need to adjust `evince_backward_search` and `evince_forward_search`, too: in both, you must set the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python2` to explicitly run Python 2.x and in `evince_backward_search` you'll have to add another parameter to the function definition of `on_sync_source` so the line reads like `def on_sync_source(self, input_file, source_link, time):`, otherwise you'll get an error message when the function is called (with 4 arguments instead of 3) (and with Sublime Text you'll also have to adjust the `cmd = re.sub(` line).

Comment: Also see https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX#toc4 for the hopefully up-to-date instructions of the LyX community.